# Python - FTP Connection Pool

Tags: python, ftp

I have a generic multiprocess script that could run any task in a multiprocess set up. I inject the task as a command line argument and use getattr to call the functions in the injected code.

```
taskModule = importlib.import_module(taskFile.replace(".py", ""))
taskContext = getattr(taskModule, 'init')()
response = pool.map_async(getattr(taskModule, 'run'), inputList)
```

The init() function creates all relevant variables for the task to execute and returns them as a dict object - the taskContext. inputList is a list of dict objects, each dict containing both the taskContext object as well as the specific item to be processed, so that each process gets a unique item to process along with a copy of the context required by the task.

One of those tasks is meant for FTP and the taskContext in that case contains information on the FTP server along with other details. The run function in the FTP task pretty much opens a connection using the context variables, uploads the required files and closes it, and this works perfectly.

However, I think it'd be good if I can set up a connection pool with multiple FTP connections at the start, as part of the init() function when the context is created, and then use them in an as-available fashion within the run method, very similar to a DB connection pool that prevents the need to open and close connections to the database every time.

Is this even feasible? If so, what's the best way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I put together a [connection_pool](https://github.com/jmeppley/ConnectionPool) module as part of a proof of concept. I'm not sure how robust it is.

I added connection closing to [this](https://github.com/niciqy/ConnectionPool) which is a bugfix of [this](https://github.com/zhouyl/ConnectionPool).

I was able to set up connection pooling of FTP and SFTP connections transferring a few thousand files over 10-20 threads.

You can install my version from conda:

```
conda install -c jmeppley connectionpool
```

Creating an FTP pool looks something like this:

```
# this is from snakemake
def connect(*args_to_use, **kwargs_to_use):
        ftp_base_class = (
            ftplib.FTP_TLS if kwargs_to_use["encrypt_data_channel"] else ftplib.FTP
        )

        ftp_session_factory = ftputil.session.session_factory(
            base_class=ftp_base_class,
            port=kwargs_to_use["port"],
            encrypt_data_channel=kwargs_to_use["encrypt_data_channel"],
            debug_level=None,
        )

        return ftputil.FTPHost(
            kwargs_to_use["host"],
            kwargs_to_use["username"],
            kwargs_to_use["password"],
            session_factory=ftp_session_factory,
        )

# a function to create a pool using the connect() method
def create_ftp_pool(pool_size, *args_to_use, **kwargs_to_use):
    create_callback = partial(connect, *args_to_use, **kwargs_to_use)
    connection_pool = ConnectionPool(create_callback, 
                                     close=lambda c: c.close(), 
                                     max_size=pool_size)


# create a pool with the arguments you'd use to create a connection
pool_size = 10
ftp_pool = create_ftp_pool(pool_size, host=...)

# use item() as a context manager
with ftp_pool.item() as connection:
    ...
```